# Can we use Query inside mongoose virtuals?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, virtual

Recently I have been working with mongoose virtuals and I was wondering if we can use query inside the mongoose virtual `get` method like this,

```
bookSchema.virtual("review").get(async function () {
  const data = await Review.findOne({ book_id: this._id });
  if (data) {
    return data
  } else {
    return false
  }
});
```

So far I think we can't do this but if that's the case is there any workaround for it?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Credits to RickN's for pointing me in the right direction.

Here's the detailed answer to the problem.

**The Problem:**

Basically the developer prior to me did not use document references anywhere in the Schema on which I could've "populated" the record. The requirement was to get book reviews for a particular book but there was no `review` field to populate on. I could've just make a new field but that won't work on already existing records so I had to find another way.

**The Idea:**

One way I thought of resolving the issue was to virtual getters. I thought I could query on the Review collection by passing the book's id but turns out you can't do that inside virtuals. Neither a `set` nor a `get` method can help here.

**The Solution:**

So finally the solution as pointed out by RickN is to use virtual populate.
You can find more about them [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals). I'll tell you what I did.

I added a "review" virtual to the book schema and used document's id as local field and book's id as foreign field similar to this

```
bookSchema.virtual("review", {
  ref: "Review",
  localField: "_id",
  foreignField: "book_id",
  justOne: false,
});
```

Here the `ref` is the reference to the Review Schema and `book_id` is the field that  schema.

There is one things to keep in mind here.

Initially the `book_id` field in my Review Schema was stored as string value (I saved it as an ObjectId and it does work when I populate on it but for some reason it was stored as string), so when I tried to match the document's Id (Type ObjectId) with `book_id` (Type String) it did not work, only after I explicitly changed the book_id to ObjectId did it work. So you might want to explicitly convert the string to ObjectId when you try to create the record using mongoose similar to this.

```
const review = await new Review({ book_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(book_id) });
```

That's it. If anyone wants to add something or correct me if I am wrong anywhere feel free to do so.

Again, credits to RickN

Answer (score 1):

The getters of virtual properties must return synchronously, so you can't execute a query in them. From your example, it seems you are looking for the [query population feature](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), which will allow you to do things like:

```
// If you have an existing instance
await someBook.populate('review');
console.log(someBook.review);

// When querying
const someOtherBook = Book.findOne().populate('review');
console.log(someOtherBook.review);
```

Comment: Hi. You are right, I would use populate for something like this, but the thing is, the developer who designed the schema did not use reference documents so I can't use populate on existing documents. I can tweak the schema a bit to take reference docs into account but that won't work for already existing docs, thats why I want virtuals to work

Comment: I think you might be looking for [this chapter](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) on the same page. I haven't got a test environment to try it out for you, but I think `{ref: 'Review', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'book_id', justOne: true}` should work.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed. I'll provide my detailed answer soon